# Kubernetes: hostPath volume does not mount

Tags: apache, ssl, docker, kubernetes

I want to create a web app using apache server with https, and I have generated certificate files using letsencrypt. I already verified that `cert.pem`, `chain.pem`, `fullchain.pem`, and `privkey.pem` are stored on the host machine. However, I cannot map them to the pod. Here is the `web-controller.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <my-wen-app-image>
        command: ['/bin/sh', '-c']
        args: ['sudo a2enmod ssl && service apache2 restart && sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND']
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http-server
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/local/myapp/https
            name: test-volume
            readOnly: false
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxx.xxx.edu
          name: test-volume
```

After `kubectl create -f web-controller.yaml` the error log says:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/usr/local/myapp/https/cert.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

This is why I think the problem is that the certificates are not mapped into the container.

Could anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there any files in `/usr/local/myapp/https`? Is the folder there? You can try commenting out the SSL settings, letting the pod actually run, and then use `kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -l name=web -o name | cut -d / -f 2) sh` to get a shell and test.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I have to mount it to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/host` rather than `/usr/local/myapp/https`

This is probably not the root cause, but it works now.

Comment: i am also getting some issue, i can see the folder created in pod but not there is no file there from my host. do you got the reason ? or solution apart from above